# bind predefined values to angular custom select

Tags: javascript, angular

I have just started learning Angular 17. For some reasons I wish to avoid Angular material. Currently I am in process of creating my own custom components using w3.css like multiple select and date picker etc. During research I found [this link](https://codeomelet.com/posts/exploring-bootstrap-5-with-angular-creating-dropdown) where multiple types of angular select are working as intended using bootstrap 5.

Few things missing are:

1. How to set predefined user values to single/multiple select
2. Collect submitted values in the form submit event.

I am not sure if that is correct way but I have tried to pass pre-selected values using Input() to the **dropdown.component.ts**. But I am not getting passed on values. Other though in my mind is to use radio buttons but not sure if that will work or not.

`<app-dropdown [items]="maxAgeData" [preselected]="selectedMaxAge" placeholder="to" (itemChange)="onMaxAgeChange($event)"></app-dropdown>`

**Github Link** - https://github.com/ZakiMohammed/ng-bootstrap-5-dropdown-app

**Working example** - https://ng-bootstrap-5-dropdown-app.netlify.app

Comment: You need to use `[ngValue]` on your `<option>` elements. [example](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#using-select-controls-in-a-template-driven-form)

Comment: @Pieterjan - I had seen this example. But the difference is that in shared link there are no options but divs with onchange event. I am not sure if div can have ngValue property.

Comment: Unfortunately, `Input()` is *not* the way to do that. If you want to have it well integrated with angular forms (both reactive forms and template driven forms), you need to learn about `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` and `ControlValueAccessor`. I think [this article](https://medium.com/@majdasab/implementing-control-value-accessor-in-angular-1b89f2f84ebf) sums it well. Can you try it ?

Comment: Thanks @ArnaudDenoyelle. Will definitely look into this.

Comment: Thanks @ArnaudDenoyelle for the guidance. I got better version for getting values {https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2nOUBwBwyU}